# yIndex is not incrementing when it is a different string value C#(Unity)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Here is my code :

```
string[] newString = new string[4];

string[,] table = new string[70, 6];

string NewPreviousValue = "placeholder";
int xIndex = -1;
int yIndex = 0;
//i have 4 game tables but it doesn't really neccessary to show all the gametables because they're all the same
if (gametable_no == 1)
{
  //this line of code print out all the GameTable_History Data
   for (int i = 0; i < tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametable_history_list.Count; i++)
   {
        newString[0] += tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametable_history_list[i].r;
        newString[0] += ",";
   }
//seperated it by a comma delimeter
string[] newChars = newString[0].Split(',');
foreach (string previousValue in newChars)
{
    if (table.GetLength(0) < xIndex)
    {
        break;
    }

    if (previousValue.Equals(NewPreviousValue) && table.GetLength(1) < yIndex)
    {
        yIndex += 1;
        table[xIndex, yIndex] = previousValue;
    }
    else
    {
        xIndex += 1;
        yIndex = 0;
        table[xIndex, yIndex] = previousValue;
    }
    NewPreviousValue = previousValue;
}
}
```

> Gametable 1 History : P ,B ,P ,B P,P ,P

The problem with this code is that the `yIndex` is not incrementing. I tried debugging the yIndex the xIndex and the previousValue it gave me this.

> LETS PRINT THE XINDEX : 2
>   LETS PRINT THE YINDEX: 0
>   LETS PRINT THE TABLE[xIndex, yIndex] : P
>
> LETS PRINT THE XINDEX : 3
>   LETS PRINT THE YINDEX: 0
>   LETS PRINT THE TABLE[xIndex, yIndex] : B
>
> LETS PRINT THE XINDEX : 4
>   LETS PRINT THE YINDEX: 0
>   LETS PRINT THE TABLE[xIndex, yIndex] : P
>
> LETS PRINT THE XINDEX : 5
>   LETS PRINT THE YINDEX: 0
>   LETS PRINT THE TABLE[xIndex, yIndex] : B P

->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

> LETS PRINT THE XINDEX : 6
>   LETS PRINT THE YINDEX: 0
>   LETS PRINT THE TABLE[xIndex, yIndex] : P
>
> LETS PRINT THE XINDEX : 7
>   LETS PRINT THE YINDEX: 0
>   LETS PRINT THE TABLE[xIndex, yIndex] : P

this should increment the yaxis because it has the same value.

What i am doing here is that if the value that is generated in `Gametable 1 History` is different then it will just increment the `x axis` and that is successful but if they are the same it must increment only the `y axis` .

Comment: Your code doesn't show where `newString` is set to anything other than an empty array. I assume that *really* `newString[0]` has the value of "P ,B ,P ,B P,P ,P"? It would be helpful to show that in the code - the easier you can make it to reproduce the problem, the more helpful the likely it is that we can help you, and the more useful the question will be to other readers too.

Comment: @DaisyShipton Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the variable names, I *expect* you intended `NewPreviousValue` to be "the value of `previousValue` in the last iteration of the loop". However, you never set that. That means your condition of

```
previousValue.Equals(NewPreviousValue)
```

will never be true unless `previousValue` is equal to "placeholder" which seems unlikely.

I suspect you're just missing:

```
NewPreviousValue = previousValue;
```

as the last statement in the loop.

(I'd also urge you to rename it to `newPreviousValue`; conventionally local variables and parameters start with a lower case letter in C#. That's unrelated to whether or not it works though.)

The next part of the condition is this:

```
table.GetLength(1) < yIndex
```

With the values you've given, `table.GetLength(1)` would be 6 - so if `yIndex` is 0, the condition is always going to be false. Additionally, I think you've got an off-by-one error. I suspect you want to change that part of the condition to

```
yIndex < table.GetLength(1) - 1
```

... although I confess it's not entirely obvious to me what you're trying to do.

Comment: @TheGinxx009: In that case, please edit the question to show something we can actually reproduce the problem with. At the moment there's too much code missing for us to help. (And I do *want* to help - but I don't want to have to guess what's going on.)

Comment: I edited it sir and put some comments on my code too.

Comment: @TheGinxx009: I've edited my answer showing that I believe the second part of your condition is the next part of the problem.

Comment: Sorry about this but i also try to declare my `int yIndex = -1;` sorry about that.

Comment: @TheGinxx009: How would that help? Your current condition will only be true if `yIndex` is *greater than or equal to* the second dimension of the array, which I'm pretty sure is the *opposite* of what you want.

Comment: That was i am missing `yIndex < table.GetLength(1)`

Comment: @TheGinxx009: Note the `- 1` - otherwise if `yIndex` is equal to `table.GetLength(1) - 1`, *then* you increment it, it won't be valid.

Comment: I don't need to i guess cause i declared already my `yIndex = -1` above

Comment: @TheGinxx009: No, you've missed my point. Suppose `yIndex` is 5 due to previous iterations, and `table.GetLength(1)` returns 6. Without the - 1 in the condition, you'd still increment `yIndex` (to 6), then try to set `table[xIndex, 6]` to a value - and *that will fail*. Additionally, I *suspect* you want to reset `xIndex` to 0 when you increment `yIndex`, but I'm not sure.